# Why token change in url

Tags: url

When submit a form while using the GET action method, changed the + token thats insert in the textfield to %2B. But why the url do this? Even other tokens like * and % will be chance.

I also wonder of this applies for the security or other things, but what are thee?

Comment: this is not a good question. Before posting always remember checking How to Ask section.

Answer (score 2):

Check out what W3Schools says about URL encoding. I think it will help you out.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Here is an exerpt:

> URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has
>   to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by
>   two hexadecimal digits. URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding
>   normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

Comment: It would be good practice to copy the selection that explains it and include that in your answer, instead of only posting a link. (it's a good link though)

Comment: It would also be good practice to cross-reference w3schools with other sources. w3schools is generally considered a sub-par reference.